Why did Yuzu name Mei’s bears?
Mei had a tiny bear that was unnamed. Yuzu decided to name it (I forgot the name) but what was her reason? Love? Sisterly actions, as they are step-sisters? Also, why did Yuzu win Mei a yellow bear? Same reasons? Different?
